# How To integrate Angular 4 With Php frontend (Existing Project) for page Rendering and backend Nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, angular, codeigniter

i have to integrate Angular 4 in my existing Php(Codeigniter) Project but i am not able to find right way to integrate angular 4 . any one know this process.please Share

Comment: Define integrate. Since both Angular and Codeigniter provide the "frontend" with templates etc do you mean you want to replace the Codeigniter frontend with an Angular frontend, or will you add one or more Angular components to the Codeigniter frontend?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node.js for backend. You wont need Php. It will be just NodeJs and Angular.

Without `NodeJS`, You can use `Php` to write your APIs and have front-end in `Angular` which will call those APIs using `HttpClinetModule`.

Comment: yes ..but my project on php and only some module convert into angular 4

Comment: Then you don't need to use NodeJS. Just Use Php as backend to create API and Angular in front-end.

Comment: no i have already integrate reactjs for some module and i want to used angular 4 in some module

Comment: Why are you mixing things..!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Angular4 you should remake the frontend in Angular4.
Then on your NodeJS backend [create rest routes](https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd)
`http://localhost:3000/tasks` for example would return a JSON object.
Then connect to your NodeJS route (`http://localhost:3000/tasks`) (from angular) using [HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientModule) and it'll return a JSON object then return that data from your service to a component that you want to display the data in, and either `subscribe` to it in the component or use the `async` pipe to unpack the data.

P.S you could also use your current PHP project and make that into an API.

Comment: my current project on php .but some module in Reactjs with webpack and  2-3 module make in angular 4 with webpack

Comment: Okay so you really should choose one language for the backend (php for example) and one for frontend (angular OR react not both) because in the best case scenario it'll work with lots of bugs and in the worst case it'll keep crashing.